# Save dynamicaly added items in layout

Tags: java, android

How do I save dynamicaly (through code) added items in layout? I mean, I added two imageViews into layout through code, but when I switch to another layout, and then get back to this one, imageViews are gone (they aren't here).

Code:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);

ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
imageView.setId(i);
imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));

layout.addView(imageView);
```

Comment: What do you mean by when you get back they are gone?  Can you elaborate your question, and possibly provide sample source code of what it is you are doing?

Comment: Yes, edited the main question above. For example I have two layouts - layout and layout2. On first setContentView(layout), I want to create these two imageViews. Then I switch to layout2 (setContentView(layout2)) and then back to layout (again through setContentView). Imageviews aren't here. What I need is draw them, but don't create them again from beginning.

Comment: You can not save anything into your xml files at runtime. I think you should try a different approach, e.g using differernt fragments for the layouts and switching those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say a second layout, do you mean a second activity ?

If yes, you can use the intent to transmit the images to the second layout, and then transmit it back to the first activity.

```
ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
bitmaps.add(yourimage);
Intent intent = new Intent(A1.this, A2.class);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("bitmaps", bitmaps);
startActivity(intent);
```

You can take it in the second Activity with :

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 if(intent.hasExtra("bitmaps")){
            ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps=  intent.getExtras().getParcelableArrayList("bitmaps");
        }
```

Comment: With layout I mean XML one.

Comment: I think you can't do that. You have to memorize them somewhere and dynamically add them again later.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to somehow manage it in following minutes. I'll accept your answer in case of success then.